# Most efficient way to store and access list of clients in Sockets.IO Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm having this simple socket.io manager, where when a user connects, he will be added to a pool of online clients and when another client (say client B), sends a message to client A, It should try to send that message only if client is in the pool. Currently I have this:

```
var connectionMap = [];
const socketHandler = (io) => {
  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.id = "some_custom_id I define";
    connectionMap.push(socket);

    socket.on("textMessage", function (message) {
      connectionMap.forEach(function (connection, index) {
        if (connection.id == message.receiver_id)
          connection.emit("textMessage", message);
      });
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", function () {
      connectionMap.splice(connectionMap.indexOf(client), 1);
    });
  });
};
```

Although this might work on a use case with small number of users, I'm looking for a solution that could scale decently without throttling the performance much. (I can't imagine a foreach running across thousands of indexes on every message sent accross the platform.) Any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an object instead of an array for `connectionMap`. On connection we set the `socket.id` as key in the object and value can be `true`. During message we can check directly in `connectionMap`if `message.receiver_id` is present. This is a significant improvement over using array as `connectionMap` because in the worst case array will take O(N) time and with object (map) you can have constant time O(1)

```js
var connectionMap = {};
const socketHandler = (io) => {
  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.id = "some_custom_id I define";
    connectionMap[socket.id] = socket;

    socket.on("textMessage", function (message) {
        if (connectionMap[message.receiver_id]) {
            connectionMap[message.receiver_id].emit("textMessage", message);
        }
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", function () {
        delete connectionMap[client];
    });
  });
};
```

Or you can use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
var connectionMap = new Map();
const socketHandler = (io) => {
  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.id = "some_custom_id I define";
    connectionMap.set(socket.id, socket);

    socket.on("textMessage", function (message) {
        if (connectionMap.has(message.receiver_id)) {
          connectionMap.get(message.receiver_id).emit("textMessage", message);
        }
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", function () {
        connectionMap.delete(client);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Works great! And changing `socket.emit` to `connectionMap[message.receiver_id].emit` will make the answer more appropriate. Consider making that change!

Comment: Thanks. Have made the changes in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use an `Object` instead of `Array`, so you can access sockets directly by `id` instead of having to search through them until you find the one you want:

```js
const connectionMap = {};
const socketHandler = io => {
  io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.id = 'some_custom_id I define';
    connectionMap[socket.id] = socket;

    socket.on('textMessage', message => {
      connectionMap[message.receiver_id].emit('textMessage', message);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', message => {
      delete connectionMap[socket.id];
    });
  });
};
```